# Как определить параметр data-id в php?

Tags: php

В строке таблицы мне необходимо задать два параметра: `data-id` и `data-name`, `data-name` у меня работает в коде. А вот параметр `data-id` определить не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="ok">
    <?
        $translates  = [
        'id' => 'Id',
        'oblastnazn' => 'Область назначения',
        'proizvoditel' => 'Производитель',
        'name1' => 'Наименование',
        'categ' => 'Категория',
        'tsokol' => 'Цоколь',
        'sklad' => 'Наличие на складе',
        'svetpotok' => 'Световой поток',
        'colorsveh' => 'Цвет свечения'
        ];  
    $fields = array_keys($translates);
    $s = "SELECT %s FROM table";
    $sql = sprintf($s, implode(',', $fields));
    /** @var PDOStatement $stmt */
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

    $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        foreach ($translates as $field=>$name) { 
            print "<div class='tab'>";
            print "<table>";
            print "<thead>";
            print "<tr>";
            print "<th style='width: 180px; height: 50px;'><center>$name</center></th>";
            print "</tr>";
            print "</thead>";
            echo "<br>";
            print "<tr >";
            print "<td  class='chenge' style='width: 180px; height: 50px;' data-id='' data-name='$field' >";
            print $row[$field];
            print "</td></tr></table></div>";
        }
         }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: А проблема случайно не в 
`print "<td  class='chenge' style='width: 180px; height: 50px;' data-id='' data-name='$field' >";` ?
Видимо `data-id` пустой.

Comment: @MikielD, так я пробовал разные варианты и у меня не высвечивалось  там нужной мне информации, вот я и прошу помощи. А значение пустое это я специально оставил.

Comment: Ну и как по-вашему нам понять почему он пустой, если вы и так в нем ничего не выводите? Какую проперть вы в data-id пишете?

Comment: @u_mulder, уже нашел ответ.

Comment: разделите отображение и логику, не насилуйте мозг людям, которые увидят ваш код https://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/,  https://habrahabr.ru/post/31270/

Comment: @apelsinka223, я не спец чтобы еще переходить на классы, я нашел один нюанс и решил свою проблему, сразу говорю не можете помочь с конкретным кодом лучше не смотрите пост вообще.

Comment: Не обязательно классы, но хотя бы на файлы разделите и передавайте результаты в параметрах. Если не хотите делать хорошо, то зачем тогда вообще делать?

Comment: @apelsinka223, вообще то я делаю проект, вот зачем.

Answer (score 1):

Решил свою проблему, чтобы data-id выводил параметр, нужно написать так

```
"<td  class='chenge' style='width: 180px; height: 50px;' data-id='$row[id]' data-name='$field' >";
```